# Autotools AC_CHECK_LIB get path of library

Tags: path, autotools, autoconf

I am a newbie with Autotools and currently trying to create a *configure.ac* file in order to check for several dependencies for the later installation of my program.

Now, I want to check the existence of certain libraries and I have found that using AC_CHECK_LIB can do the trick. I think PCK_CHECK_MODULES could help too but I would like to stick to the former unless PCK_CHECK_MODULES solved my problem:

AC_CHECK_LIB does what is expected to do which is to look for the library and perform an action if found or another one if not found, but, my question then is:

If AC_CHECK_LIB finds my library, how can I obtain the exact path of this library? That is to say, if the AC_CHECK_LIB I have is:

**AC_CHECK_LIB (foo, function, [action-if-found], [action-if-not-found])**

Is there any way for me to get the *exact* path of this **foo** library if it is found?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

> If AC_CHECK_LIB finds my library, how can I obtain the exact path of this library?

`AC_CHECK_LIB` does not provide any mechanism by which you could do so.  It does not determine an actual location itself.  Per [its documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Libraries.html#index-AC_005fCHECK_005fLIB-341), this is what it actually does:

> Test whether the library `library` is available by trying to link a test
>   program that calls function `function` with the library. `function` should
>   be a function provided by the library.

When `AC_CHECK_LIB` succeeds, then, it knows only that the linker found a library corresponding to the given library name that provides a function having the specified function name.  It doesn't know *where* the linker found it.  On the flip side, when that macros *does not* find a library, that does not necessarily mean it is unavailable, but rather that the linker does not find it subject to the link options, if any, in effect at that point.

Note, too, that that's perfectly satisfactory for many purposes.  You need to know the actual location only if you want to use that to locate some other, related resource.  And it's rare that `configure` can find a library without help, yet needs extra information to locate related resources.

Comment: John, I think you are right and for some cases it should be enough just to make sure the library is "there". However I do need to know _where_ that library is. I was also thinking of using this command: `echo "$(ldconfig -p | grep foo | tr ' ' '\n' | grep /)"` which would return the path of that library if found by ldconfig but it's not very elegant and I believe it won't work for static ones. From there comes my question.

Comment: @Alberto, it was my belief that `ldconfig` and its outputs are not directly related to finding shared libraries at build time.  In any case, I suspect that you have an X-Y problem here.  If you need the location of *something else* related to the shared lib, then you would be best off adding a variable (`AC_ARG_VAR`) or option (`AC_ARG_WITH`) by which its location can be communicated to `configure`, and by searching some standard locations when that mechanism is not used.